# Why does this static const int member variable appear to be accessible publicly in array definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, access-control, static-variables

I make the following declarations:

```
class Servo {

protected:

    static const int maxServos = 16;    
    static Servo servos[maxServos]; //Array declaration
};

Servo Servo::servos[Servo::maxServos]; //Array definition
```

...and it compiles, which is great !  But I don't understand why it compiles because it seems to me that maxServos is protected and I am using it in a global scope when I define the array.  I tried using it in another global context and indeed I did get a compile error:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << Servo::maxServos;  //This will not compile.
}
```

So what is going on ?  Is the whole definition of the array somehow scoped by the namespace qualifying the array ? Is it a compiler glitch ?

I am using g++ -std::c++11 on a Raspberry PI using Lubuntu 16.04 O/S.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This definition

```
Servo Servo::servos[Servo::maxServos]; //Array definition
```

is not global scope, it's class scope due to the (first) `Servo::` scope qualifier.  You can make this even clearer by removing the redundant second scope qualifier:

```
Servo Servo::servos[maxServos]; //Array definition
```

and it still compiles just fine.

TL;DR -- the scope qualifier on the declarator makes everything after in the same declarator in that scope.

Comment: "_everything after in the same declarator in that scope_" what about `C::mem_type C::static_obj;`? Is `C::mem_type` morally after `C::static_obj`?

Comment: @curiousguy: `C::mem_type` is a declaration specifier and not part of the declarator at all.  Its also physically before the declarator, so could not be easily parsed otherwise (morality doesn't enter into it).

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. The Q was about access control to protected names. "Should access control be done as from a member, incl. for `C::mem_type` in `C::mem_type C::static_obj`?" was the precision I asked.

Comment: I think I have just had to completely update the way I view the scope of namespace qualifiers in expressions.  I have been imagining it working another way for years (just affecting the symbol which is qualified).  Thanks for your insight.